# How do I verify the latest Dell A10 BIOS is installed?

Tags: drivers, updates, dell, acpi

[Dell released the A10 BIOS 19 May 2008 and updated it 21 June 2013](https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/drivers/driversdetails?driverid=r186796&oscode=ww1&productcode=latitude-d620).

From Terminal:

```
user@latitude-d620:~$ sudo dmidecode -s bios-version
A10
user@latitude-d620:~$ sudo dmidecode -s bios-release-date
05/16/2008
```

This date does not match Dell's. `man dmidecode` does state, "[Because it does not] probe for the actual hardware[,] the presented information [is] possibly unreliable." Is this an example of unreliableness? Does this date indicate when the BIOS was last updated, demonstrating mine is outdated? or only the release date itself, implying nothing about when mine was last updated?

How do I determine whether my "A10" is the 2013 updated version?

Comment: why don't you enter BIOS and check the versionnumber?

Comment: @Rinzwind, that shows the same information. I followed Dell's instructions and presumably successfully updated the BIOS using their EXE file, but it still shows the same information. I suppose the next step is to Tweet to DellCaresPro about how the update doesn't change the date or indicate successful installation and hope for their guidance.